# Magento 2 - Access has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: magento2, html, cors

With my html2canvas code I'm trying to print on a pdf document an image that comes from an external resource.
The image is in the  tag.

The error it brings me is this:

```
Access to image at 'cdn.site2.com' from origin 'www.mysite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN service not configured (cdn.site2.com)

External resource cdn.site2.com should whitelist [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)